# UIDropShadowView showing during Flip Horizontal modal transition

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uistoryboardsegue

I'm attempting to transition from 1 view controller to another, with the illusion that ViewController 1 flipped over to ViewController 2 as a form sheet. However, during the transition, there's a visible gray UIDropShadowView that's ruining the effect.

third from the left
[image: third from the left]

Here's a gif showcasing the problem:

[image: Here's a gif showcasing the problem:]

And lastly, I've attached a Sample Project showcasing the problem:
[Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lma9lbzdmny2khu/Test.zip?dl=0)

What am I doing wrong, or how can I resolve this to create the illusion I'm looking for?

Note: I've confirmed this happens on an actual iPad